# Javascript events multiplying

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium, addeventlistener, appcelerator-mobile

I can't see the forest through the trees. I have a contacts tab with a [tableView](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView-object) containing [rows](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-object) that can be deleted. If (in the same session) I delete 'n' number of rows, the subsequent events are called 'n' times.

[Here is my code](http://pastie.org/2170370). (I tried to pare this down to isolate the problem.)

The specific event that is being duplicated (...triplicated, etc) is `ui.contactDestroyed` because I am getting multiple [AlertDialogs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-object) as well as multiple resulting `app.updateContacts` and `ui.contactsUpdated` fires in my log.

Thanks for any critiques of my code (related to the issue or not).

**Note**: According to my server log, the `otg.remote.destroyContact` XHR is appropriately being sent once for each legitimate request. The `otg.remote.getContacts` XHR is sent multiple times because it is tied to the culprit, `ui.contactDestroyed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 197 and line 188 should not be in the eventListener, the way the code is written right now, everytime someone deletes something, you are adding a new eventListener, that is why it is happening multiple times.

Add application wide eventListeners **once**